# Excel - Bar Chart with horizontal reference line on each bar

Tags: excel, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I want to create a bar chart that compares groups at 2 points in time, t1 vs t2. But instead of having them side by side, I want to have t2(now) as a bar and t1(before) as a horizontal line.
Similar to what you can do with Tableau (for those who use it). Except it does not have to be Horizontal Bar Chart, can be just the normal vertical one.

Here is an example of the dataset that I have and how I need it to look like.

```
Metric  WeekEnding  Bucket1 Bucket2 Bucket3 Bucket4
Debt    16/09/2016  88       126    116         89
Debt    23/02/2017  61        87    65          82
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like your chart does not reflect your data in two ways. The bars look like they are for series 16/09/2016, but you said the bars should reflect t2 (now), and the other series is more recent. Also,  the lines don't seem to reflect either series--for example, in Bucket 2, the line segment is somewhere around 115, and that is neither series 1 nor series 2. So, in my response below, my resulting image is somewhat different from your chart.

One way to do this is to make a 2D clustered column chart, change the t1 series to XY scatter, then make the marker a line segment and make the segment as wide as you need it (unfortunately I don't see a way to increase the width without changing the height).

More detail (note that my instructions are using Excel 2013): First, select the chart data and choosing "2D clustered column type". Then right-click one of the bars from the t1 series and choose "Change Series Chart Type". Then change the t1 series to "Scatter" (i.e., XY scatter), and uncheck "Secondary Axis" to plot the series on the same axis. Then right-click a t1 series point, choose "Format Data Series", and under "Marker Options", choose the line segment marker type under "Built-In". Increase the size as high as necessary. You can reduce the border width and that will reduce the width slightly.

Here is the resulting plot. I uploaded my Excel file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/book1_21).

[image: Here is the resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed line's width and height by using an image file instead of the horizontal line in the marker choice list.  Create a .png of a straight line (in Paint, say) and then crop all the space around the image (in Photos, perhaps) to be exactly the size and shape you want.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35330884)